# How can I center items in a table in html?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble centering my code as I'm new to web development.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I would like to center it so it looks better.

My html:

```
<table style="justify-content: center;">
<tr><th style='padding:25px'><h2>Grade 9</h2>
- <a href='regular9.php'>Regular 9</a><br>
- <a href='honors9.php'>Honors 9</a><br>
</th><th style='padding:25px'>
<h2>Grade 10</h2>
- <a href='regular10.php'>Regular 10</a><br>
- <a href='honors10.php'>Honors 10</a><br>
</th>
<th style='padding:25px'>
<h2>Grade 11</h2>
- <a href='courses11.php'>Courses 11</a><br>
- <a href='diploma11.php'>Diploma 11</a><br>
</th>
<th style='padding:25px'>
<h2>Grade 12</h2>
- <a href='courses12.php'>Courses 12</a><br>
- <a href='diploma12.php'>Diploma 12</a><br>
</th>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to center ? the whole table or the columns?

Comment: Things inside the table look centered to me. So you probably want to center the table. Instead of `<table style="justify-content: center;">` try `<table style="justify-content: center;margin:0 auto;">`. This might not work, because of stuff that surrounds the table. You didn't include that code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this

```
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto;
```

replace

```
<table style="justify-content: center;">
```

with

```
<table style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
```

or better
css:

```
table.center {
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

html:

```
<table class="center">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the Table's Column Try text-align: center;